# Flutter Deep Link Firebase in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, deep-linking

My deep link works fine on Android and transfers information to the app, but it doesn't work on iOS
Firebase Link

```
https://dvzpl.com
```

my short link

```
https://dvzpl.com/6BG2
```

my domain

```
https://dovizpanel.com/
```

my associated domain

```
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>webcredentials:dvzpl.com</string>
        <string>applinks:dvzpl.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

how to fix ?
When I open the short link in the browser, it goes into the app but does not transfer the data in ios , android working not problams

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
    <string>https://dovizpanel.com/blog</string>
    <string>https://dovizpanel.com/exchanger</string>
    <string>https://dovizpanel.com/link</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a custom domain for firebase dynamic links follow the instructions below:

In your Xcode project's Info.plist file, create a key called FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains and set it to your app's Dynamic Links URL prefixes. For example:

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
  <string>https://dvzpl.com</string>
</array>
```

You can find more details directly in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains).

Comment: not working bro not passed data to app

Comment: If the app opens, but the data is not there, most likely the problem is elsewhere; I would need to look at your implementation.

Comment: You can check that in dynamic link -> data is added as query parameters or the path parameters .

As that you can get the data from the dynamic link